# Convert an exception to a warning in order to unblock executing the remaining code (C#)

Tags: c#

I have the following code which includes sending an email using Mail.Send Delegated Permission:

```
public async Task Process()
{
    // var jobs = <get-a-list-of-jobs>
    await foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        if (job.Time == DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0))
        {
            await SendMailAsync("subject", "content");
        }
        
        //remaining code
    }
}

public async Task SendMailAsync(string subject, string content)
{
    var message = new Message
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            Content = content
        }
    };

    await _graphClient.Me
            .SendMail(message, SaveToSentItems: true)
            .Request().WithUsernamePassword(<sender-address>, <sender-password>)
            .PostAsync();
}
```

Currently when I run this code, if an exception occurs at the line:

```
await SendMailAsync("subject", "content");
```

the remaining code doesn't execute. How do I update this code to continue executing the remaining code by converting the exception to a warning?

Comment: Using a try catch block is not sufficient?  Please define what you mean by warning.

Comment: Agreed. Put `await SendMailAsync` in a `try` block and do whatever you want in the `catch` block (log a warning, etc.) There's no concept of a "warning" in .NET - you either catch and handle an exception or let it bubble up.

Comment: Apologize if my title/question is not right - basically I need the code to continue executing even if an exception happens at this line. await SendMailAsync("subject", "content"); I will update my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a concept of a "warning" in C#. If an exception is thrown, it needs to either be handled or allowed to bubble up. How you handle that exception determines if the code continues or halts.

So wrap your `await` call in a `try` block and add a `catch` block that does something:

```
public async Task Process()
{
    // var jobs = <get-a-list-of-jobs>
    await foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        if (job.Time == DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0))
        {
            try
            {
                await SendMailAsync("subject", "content");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)   // should probably see what exceptions `SendMail` throws and catch them explicitly
            {
                do something?  Log the exception? 
            }
        }
        
        //remaining code
    }
}
```

Now `remaining code` will execute so long as your catch block doesn't re-throw the exception or throw a new one.